# Reducing Repeated State in Functions React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```js
function Home() {
  const [view_points, setViewPoints] = React.useState(true);
  const [view_races, setViewRaces] = React.useState(true);
  const [view_wpm, setViewWPM] = React.useState(true);

  function handleViewPoints(e) {
    setViewPoints(e.target.checked);
  }
  function handleViewWPM(e) {
    setViewWPM(e.target.checked);
  }
  function handleViewRaces(e) {
    setViewRaces(e.target.checked);
  }

  <Step4
    viewraces={handleViewRaces}
    viewwpm={handleViewWPM}
    viewpoints={handleViewPoints}
  />

  <Step5
    viewpoints={view_points}
    viewraces={view_races}
    viewwpm={view_wpm}
  />
```

They are used as:

```js
<Checkbox onChange={props.viewpoints}>Points</Checkbox>
<Checkbox onChange={props.viewraces}>Races</Checkbox>
<Checkbox onChange={props.viewwpm}>WPM</Checkbox>
```

Which is a lot of repetition.

Are there any recommended ways to reduce the repeated code without transitioning to a class-based component?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use state as object instead of boolean.So single state is enough

**[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-sound-dr89v)**

```
const [state,setState] = useState({
   view_points:true,
   view_races:true,
   view_wpm:true
})
```

Comment: How should I put the states in function props (as in the first code block) and to children elements (second code block)?

Comment: you just pass the function as props or pass the `setState` and update the state inside the child check [my fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-sound-dr89v)

Comment: Instead of giving `one: "clicked from child one"`, are the possible ways to make the string into event attributes? I have `event.target.value` and `event.target.checked` depending on the input type. There are also multiple input attributes and I'd like them to be dynamically added to the setState function.

Comment: In case you want to take a look at [my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ant-design-multi-step-form-6hm7t?file=/src/components/Step1.js), the first block is from UserForm.js and the second block is from Step1.js