# how to get all the state of a functional component?

Tags: reactjs

is there any way to get all the state of a functional component? without using 1 object as the state and do something like that :

```
const [state,setState] = useState({
      showHomeButton: false,
      key : val,
      key2 : val2,
     
  })
```

Comment: Do you need something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030606/reducing-repeated-state-in-functions-react

Comment: @prasanth no , I wrote in the question that I cannot use this solution.

any other idea?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the current code exmaple you have put up? technically you can use a single object if you want/need to.

Comment: @masterG, if you don't wish to use single Object, then I think the answer to your question is no. Either use one big state, or many small states